# Determining which value in a row, if any, is greater

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a large table of data where I need to find out if, along one row, any values are greater than a threshold number. If it finds a number, I need it to either return that number, or return the column header so I can find that number.

One problem that may occur is that there may be multiple values that exceed this threshold.

The data can't be sorted in ascending or descending order because that may mess up other orders, or take them out of the necessary column they need to be in.

Below is a small snippet of data that I'm dealing with. I need to know if the numbers are ever greater (more positive) than -50. I need to know which numbers exceed it and/or which column it's in.

I'd rather it not be vba or macro, but if needs be then such is life.

Help? [Two Sample data rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTnL0.jpg)

Comment: Do you just want the numbers highlighted, or do you want some kind of MsgBox? Do you just want the cells stored some how. Depending on what your output is, different approaches will be easier.

Comment: you can do this with formula, so =if(a1:z1>=-50,column(a1:z1),"") in an array, this will give results like {4,5,10} where these are the column numbers, you can then use SMALL(array,k) to get the column numbers and do what you need.  Similarly put it in formula based CF to highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **E12**, in **F1** enter the array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:E1>-50,A1:E1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Note:

If all the values are less than -50, the formula will return **0**

Comment: That's money! So if I'm understanding this one correctly, it cycles through A1->E1, comparing them -50. Then, if they are true, it basically it into an array. Then it compares all the "True" values and takes the minimum. Is that all correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the Home Tab choose Conditional Formatting

[image]
Select the Range that you what Conditionally Formatted.  Enter the formula that what evaluated.  In this case >-50.
[image]

Comment: I thought about that, but the only problem is that the threshold number changes on each row. Is there a way to quickly change the condition arguments without manually typing in the change?